# AWS S3 - access private file from URL

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, private, aws-sdk, bucket

I am using ASP.NET AWS SDK to upload files to S3 bucket from my web application.

```
public static void UploadFile(string filePath)
{
        using (_client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var request = new PutObjectRequest()
            {
                Key = String.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetExtension(filePath)),
                BucketName = _bucketName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,               
                FilePath = filePath
            };

            _client.PutObject(request);
        }
}
```

Since it is a private file (CannedACL is Private), I cannot access the file from URL. (https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/image.png)

But I want to access the file from url ONLY if I am logged to the asp.net web application that I developed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a 'private' file, you either need to use an **API call** that includes authentication information or you could use a **Pre-Signed URL**.

A [Pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) is a time-limited URL that includes an encrypted authorization string, permitting access to a private object.

The pre-signed URL can be generated by a few lines of code and requires access credentials of an IAM User that has permission to access the private file.

See documentation: [Generate a Pre-signed Object URL using AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html)